# How to get current page URL with gecko?

Tags: java, android-studio, firefox-addon-sdk, gecko, geckoview

I am trying to make my android web browser open only specific urls. Because of that, I want to check if loaded url meets the requirements, and according to that to do something. I saw many answers about WebView, but since I have to use open source browser (Mozilla Firefox) I am using gecko. Here is my code, I tried to do something with onLoadRequest but I do not know how to make it work. Thanks.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GeckoView view = findViewById(R.id.geckoView);
    GeckoSession session = new GeckoSession();
    GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);

    session.open(runtime);
    view.setSession(session);
    session.loadUri("https://www.google.com");

    GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest loadRequest=new GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest();

   session.getNavigationDelegate().onLoadRequest(session,loadRequest);


}

@Override
public void onLoadRequest(GeckoSession session, GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate.LoadRequest request)
{
    if(request.uri.contains("mail"))
        GeckoResult.fromValue(AllowOrDeny.ALLOW);
    else
        GeckoResult.fromValue(AllowOrDeny.DENY);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeckoView heavily relies on its delegates to allow for app-specific handling of most relevant mechanics and events.

In short, there are runtime and session delegates, set on [`GeckoRuntime`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoRuntime.html) and [`GeckoSession`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoSession.html) respectively.
The general pattern is that for each delegate there is a `set{DelegateName}Delegate()` method to attach delegates to the runtime or session with one exception being [`RuntimeTelemetry.Delegate`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/RuntimeTelemetry.Delegate.html) which is set in [`GeckoRuntimeSettings`](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/org/mozilla/geckoview/GeckoRuntimeSettings.html) instead.

Delegate methods are called by `GeckoView` and should not be called by the app.

In your case, you want to implement the `NavigationDelegate` and set your implementation on the `GeckoSession` to override the default top-level page load behavior.

```
class MyNavigationDelegate implements GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate {
    @Override
    public GeckoResult<AllowOrDeny> onLoadRequest(
            final GeckoSession session,
            final LoadRequest request) {
        // TODO: deny/allow based on your constrains.
    }

    // TODO: You should implement the rest of the delegate to handle page load
    // errors and new session requests triggered by new-tab/window requests.
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GeckoView view = findViewById(R.id.geckoView);
    GeckoSession session = new GeckoSession();
    GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.create(this);

    session.setNavigationDelegate(new MyNavigationDelegate());

    session.open(runtime);
    view.setSession(session);
    session.loadUri("https://www.google.com");
}
```

For more details, please consult the [API reference](https://mozilla.github.io/geckoview/javadoc/mozilla-central/index.html) and the [GeckoView Example](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/geckoview_example/src/main/java/org/mozilla/geckoview_example/GeckoViewActivity.java) implementation.